# Change HTML tag dir value to none if dir ="rtl"

Tags: jquery

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar"></html>
$( "html[dir=='rtl']" ).attr("dir", "");
```

I want to change the dir value none. If dir="rtl" with jquery. 
I have tried the above code, but not working.
Any solutions.

Comment: check my answer. its updated with auto change listener

Comment: Accept the answer which is more informative and helped you to close this thread or let us know is there any other issue exist from your question

Answer (score 4):

```
$( "html[dir='rtl']" ).attr("dir", "");
```

try this. use `=` instead of `==` for checking equality.

or

```
var dir = $("html").attr("dir");
if(dir == "rtl")
{
   $("html").attr("dir", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below. you added double equal to operator.

```
$( "html[dir='rtl']" ).attr("dir", "");
```

or Listening auto by whenever any changes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("html").bind('change', function(event) {
      if( $( "html" ).attr("dir") == "rtl" ) {
        $( "html" ).attr("dir", "");
      }
   });
});
```

Definition:

```
  $("<selector>" ).attr("attribute Name", "attribute value");
```

Comment: isn't it `name` and `value`?